# RadioButton and image

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, toggle

I try to set up images instead of bullet for my RadioButtons. I've 10 RadioButtons but I can't setup my FishImg for all. Only the rb I clicked just before displays the imgFish.

My Style

```
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgFish}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="Images/empty.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgHero}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgFish}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My XAML

```
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="hvP1" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Name="hvP2" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Name="hvP3" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Name="hvP4" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Name="hvP5" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Name="hvP6" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Name="hvP7" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Name="hvP8" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Name="hvP9" />
                <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" Name="hvP10" />
```

Comment: If I read this right, you want the fish image to display from the very beginning.  Then checking the checkbox will give you either a hero or fish based on wether or not the checkbox state is Checked or NotChecked.  If that is the case you must initialize Content with the fishImg.  The Style.Trigger code only executes after clicking a checkbox as you've found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found it today even if I was pretty sure I tried it yesterday... may be tired.

Here a working solution

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Image Source="Images/on.png" x:Key="imgOn"/>
    <Image Source="Images/off.png" x:Key="imgOff"/>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="Images/off.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgOn}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgOff}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Name="rb1" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rb2" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rb3" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rb4" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```