# C# WPF: Grouping of radio buttons in datagrid not working when radio buttons displayed as image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, radio-button

I am using the code from stack overflow question:

[RadioButton and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573358/radiobutton-and-image)

This is working fine, but since I activated the style in my radio buttons, the grouping does not work correctly. It should group the radio buttons per row, but instead it is grouped by the whole datagrid:

[Grouping by whole grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PATjZ.png)

The Binding of the Id ensures that the groupname should be unique of each row, which does work when I remove the style attribute of my radio buttons.

Code of my radio buttons, which are included in a wpf datagrid:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton
                                x:Name="radioPlayNext"
                                MinWidth="50"
                                Command="{Binding PlayNextClipCommand}"
                                GroupName="{Binding Id}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Handling, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Handling_e.Handling_PlayNextClipInList}}"
                                Style="{StaticResource StyleRadioPlayNext}" />

                            <RadioButton
                                x:Name="radioLoopClip"
                                MinWidth="50"
                                Command="{Binding LoopClipCommand}"
                                GroupName="{Binding Id}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Handling, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Handling_e.Handling_LoopClip}}"
                                Style="{StaticResource StyleRadioLoopClip}" />

                            <RadioButton
                                x:Name="radioPlayAndHold"
                                MinWidth="50"
                                Command="{Binding PlayAndHoldLastFrameCommand}"
                                GroupName="{Binding Id}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Handling, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Handling_e.Handling_PlayAndHoldLastFrameOfClip}}"
                                Style="{StaticResource StyleRadioPlayHold}" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Style is as follows:

```
    <Image x:Key="imgOnNext" Source="../../Images/NEXT_on.png" />
    <Image x:Key="imgOffNext" Source="../../Images/NEXT_off.png" />
    <!--  Style for radio button play next clip in list  -->
    <Style x:Key="StyleRadioPlayNext" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image
                            Width="32"
                            Height="32"
                            Source="../../Images/NEXT_off.png" />
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgOnNext}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource imgOffNext}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You don't have to bind a unique value to the GroupName. Just use simple string values. The name has to be unique within the scope, which is the DataTemplate. Also don't use the Content property to show the image. This makes using the RadioButton.Content as label impossible. Adding the extra Image to the Grid is also pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have linked is a bad one.

Better use a [`BulletDecorator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.bulletdecorator?view=net-5.0#examples) instead of the `Content` to show the check state image. This way you are still able to use the `Content` property to show a button label.

Generally, if you don't know how a control is properly styled then lookup the corresponding control's style and template: [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

The `GroupName` must be unique within the current scope, which is the `DataTemplate`. Each `DataTemplate` is its own scope. Therefore you don't have to bind `GroupName` to a unique ID, which very likely introduces some issues. It's redundant.
Simply set the `GroupName` to individual names like you would do with the `x:Name` directive.

For performance reasons, you should always choose `StaticResource` over `DynamicResource`.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="imgOnNext" Source="../../Images/NEXT_on.png" />
    <Image x:Key="imgOffNext" Source="../../Images/NEXT_off.png" />

    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <BulletDecorator>
              <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="BulletContent" 
                                  Content="{StaticResource imgOffNext}" />
              </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
              <ContentPresenter />
            </BulletDecorator>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="BulletContent" 
                        Property="Content" 
                        Value="{StaticResource imgOnNext}" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <RadioButton GroupName="A"
                           Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" 
                           Content="{Binding SomeValue}" />

              <RadioButton GroupName="A"
                           Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                           Content="{Binding SomeOtherValue}" />

              <RadioButton GroupName="B"
                           Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                           Content="{Binding SomeValue}" />
              <RadioButton GroupName="B"
                           Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                           Content="{Binding SomeOtherValue}" />

            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid> 
</Window>
```